# GORM Raw sql not getting executed

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a simple UPDATE SQL statement that I am trying to execute:

```golang
if err := gormDB.Raw("UPDATE orders SET item_id = ? WHERE client_id = ?", "item1", "client1").Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
```

No errors are being returned, but my query is seemingly not being executed on the database. Nothing is logged, and no database changes are persisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `Raw` by itself does not execute the query. One way to execute the operation and to retrieve the results is using the `Rows()` method:

```golang
if _, err := gormDB.Raw("UPDATE orders SET item_id = ? WHERE client_id = ?", "item1", "client1").Rows(); err != nil {
    return err
}
// Parse rows...
```

In my case however, I did not need to access the returned result, so I opted to use the `Exec` method, which immediately executes the given SQL:

```golang
if err := gormDB.Exec("UPDATE orders SET item_id = ? WHERE client_id = ?", "item1", "client1").Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. gormDB.Raw() will return (tx *DB), it would not execute,
   generally, it use to query.
2. use directly gormDB.exec()